# How to enable fstack-protector in Android gradle build process

Tags: android, android-security

Some security advice has suggested enabling fstack-protector when compiling my Android binary.

Q1> is this applicable if I'm not using NDK?

Q2> where do I configure in my gradle build process?

Answer (score 3):

1. No, I believe it's not applicable if you're not using NDK, as it's C++-related stuff.
2. To add - put related C++ flag "-fstack-protector-all" (for example) to module build.gradle file android -> defaultConfig -> externalNativeBuild -> cmake -> cppFlags.

`externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-fstack-protector-all"
    }
}`